# Why is it not possible to edit privileges for VIEWs?

Tags: pgadmin

In PGAdmin-1.14, If I open the properties of a TABLE or SEQUENCE, I get a privileges tab where GRANTs can be added or revoked for users and/or groups.

The properties tab for VIEWs does not have such a tab, however, I can still change privileges through the Grant Assistent.

Is that an oversight, or is there a deeper meaning to this?

Comment: Hrm, according to http://www.pgadmin.org/visualtour16.php it looks like PGAdmin-1.16 might add that, so probably really just an oversight which got fixed in the meantime.